# Where to extract sources-27_r01.zip?

Tags: android-studio

I'm manually downloading every android studio components as the software itself always fails to do so.
I've nearly completed fixing everything but two.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRK0I.jpg)

Of the two, android studio tries to download sources-27_01.zip first. The 35.3MB one.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7fP9.jpg)

I manually downloaded it with the link. But I can't figure out where to place it.
I've tried placing in in various places with names in \AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources but with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to extract all files from sources-27_01.zip to  \AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-27 ?
When you are  downloading sources for some API (I see that you downloading sources for 27 API) it creates inside sources folder, folder for each API sources.
Here is a list of folders and files inside my path \AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-25

[image: list of folders and files inside my path \AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-25]

Comment: Thanks. Extracting the zip file and copying everything inside the src folder to AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-27 solved it.